# How to start two different process in heroku dyno

Tags: node.js, heroku, worker

I am trying to lunch two different process in same heroku dyno, one worker and one web.
I have Procfile as under

```
    worker: node worker.js
    web: npm start
```

index.js is invoked by npm start which is a regular express server and worker.js is a cron  scheduling file which is as under:

```
    const redis = require('redis');
    const cron = require("node-cron");
    const sync = require('./modules/sync/shopify/controller/index');
    let client = redis.createClient(process.env.REDIS_URL)

    client.on('connect', function () {
        console.log('Redis client connected');
    });

    client.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('Something went wrong ' + err);
    });

    cron.schedule("*/3 * * * *", function () {
        let shop = { id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000), sync_type: 1, current: 0, next: 0, offset: 250, total: 1000 }
        client.rpush(['sync', JSON.stringify(shop)], function (err, reply) {
            console.log("Queue lenght", reply);
        });
    });

    cron.schedule("* * * * *", function () {
        sync.initiate(client);
    });
```

But only web is run. How can I start both the process?
Any kind of suggestion are highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

everything was right, I just had to visit the dashboard and change the state of the attached dyno to on which was off by default.